# how to copy all files in subfolders to the parent folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to copy all files within subfolders to the parent folder. But want to create a new folder in it by the name "copied" in whichever folder i have copied my batch file. I tried this command.

```
FOR /R %%# IN (*.*) DO XCOPY "%%#"
```

It does the job but it keeps asking to rewrite files. Also wasn't sure how to create the folder name in which i have copied my batch file into.

Comment: I don't believe it does its job as you didn't specify a copy target... Do you want to overwrite already existing files or not? I don't understand the thing with the sub-directory `copied`, so please clarify your directory structure and what to be copied where...

Comment: It look like `ROBOCOPY` using the /XD switch might work.